# Convert two lists into a dictionary of X and Y Format

Tags: javascript, python, django, dictionary, chart.js

I have two lists containing around 300 decimal numbers. That I need to convert into a dictionary format like below in order to plot a scatter graph using the values within the two lists as X and Y coordinates with Chart.JS.

This is the format that Chart.JS requires the data to be in.

```
           data: [{
               x: -10,
               y: 0
           }, {
               x: 0,
               y: 10
           }, {
               x: 10,
               y: 5
           }]
```

I've been trying to do this in a number of different ways but each time I get it wrong. Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: provide sample input list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has already written the Javascript solution, I will describe Python way.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5];

data = []

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    data.append({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

or shorter and pythonic style:

```py
data = [{'x': x, 'y': y} for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate such an array.

The second parameter of the `map` function is the index, you can get the `y` value by that index.

```js
const features = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const labels = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66];

const coords = features.map((x, i) => ({ x, y: labels[i] }));

console.log(coords);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the python solution worked best for me, however having both Javascript and python solutions is helpful for others looking for the same solution. Great work.